How can I devote enough time to my research when there are other things I am passionate about?
I am a Master of Science student and I am working on my thesis. Although I know that I need to devote enough time to my research in order to finish the thesis and improve my publications, I cannot do it because there are other activities that I am interested in doing. For example, I play piano and guitar, and I am passionate about learning music theory and maybe becoming an expert in the future. In fact, recently I've decided to dedicate 3-4 hours of my daily time to music, and now every day when I get out of bed, it's the first thing I want to do. Usually I cannot stick to only 3-4 hours and even thinking about it distracts me when I am doing research for my thesis. There are also other things I really like to do every day, like playing chess, solving math problems (although it is completely unrelated to my research).
In summary, I think that with the presence of all these activities (distractions!), I cannot focus on doing research. I'm not sure what to do in this situation. Should I really give up my passion for music, which is such a big distraction? On the one hand, I don't want to sacrifice it for my research (which has been less rewarding so far), and on the other hand, I find it very difficult to be productive in my research while spending time on music.

Gotta prioritize, that's all there is to it. Figure out what you care most about, and realize that indulging those things may cause other things to be inadequately served...

@paulgarrett Thanks a lot for the advice.

My personal story:
I was in the same situation in the middle of math PhD, but it was more a question of staying or not in academia. And after pondering for a year or so I decided that I'm not ready to live without sufficiently enjoying my side interests(reading/writing/learning new non-math subjects). This lead me to make a decision on not staying in academia as I hope to have more free time(and more importantly: intellectual energy) with a non-research job. But I still want a good enough thesis. Right now I'm able to do both, research and side work, but not squeezing fully neither of them.

Please realise that 4+ hours every day is a massive time investment. That’s basically another >60% job on top of your official work. This is far beyond a side distraction like a hobby, and very likely not sustainable in terms of health and wellbeing. If you don’t prioritise quickly, life will prioritise for you the hard way.

FWIW, I am not seeing how this is an academia question. This isn’t terribly different from focusing on your career versus focusing on your passions. Any answer will be a generic productivity/life focus/self help advice that would equally apply outside of academia. (In fact I just binned my answer draft after realising I was basically summarising the last productivity book I read.)

Growing up is hard, sometimes you have to make choices you don't like. Either way, I vote to close, this is hardly an academia question.

See also other questions ... working while studying https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/142827/4484 or social life plus academic life https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15175/4484

It's sort of specific to academia in that focusing on research/finishing a thesis is a different challenge to focusing on non-research jobs. I found finishing my masters thesis (on a topic I was pretty interested in!) much more difficult than reliably showing up to work at a job I wasn't that interested in.

@deee Hence I said "career" instead of "job". Sure this doesn’t mirror any deadbeat job,  but academia is hardly the only "job" that benefits from a long term time investment and passion.

Unfortunately you need to choose, there's just not enough time for everything. E.g. when I graduated from high school I could reasonably have studied any of the three hard sciences (physics, chemistry & biology), or mathematics, or a few other topics (like law & medicine). I obviously can't do all of them, so I had to choose one. Was that choice the best one? There's no way to tell, but it was a choice. I made the choice and I live with it.
You're encountering the same issue dressed in different words: you've already chosen a topic for your MSc, but are now finding that perhaps you should've chosen something else entirely (in this context, music is also a subject that can be studied, see e.g. the Berklee College of Music). What do you want to do? You can't do both, you must choose one to specialize in.
Not knowing anything about your circumstances, I'd say focus on your MSc first since you're already so deep into it; even if you switch now it'll be a while before you can start formally studying music anyway. Then after finishing your MSc, think about studying music.

If you are finding you can't direct your attention to tasks you need to complete to the extent that it is affecting your ability to work, it may be worth speaking to a medical professional to ask about being assessed for a specific learning difficulty (e.g. ADHD). Unless you plan to make music into a career then you will have to find ways to force yourself to do things other than music in order to hold down a job.
If you are working on your master's thesis you are presumably close to the end of a degree you've put a lot of effort into, and it would be a shame not to finish it. You can try setting timers or saving the fun things like music as a reward for hitting a certain word count each day. You can try leaving the house and going somewhere to work where it's harder to access the distracting activities. But you need to work out how to direct your attention to things you need to do, even when they're less immediately gratifying.

I hate to say it, but if you aren't at least as passionate about your research as you are about other things, then you should, perhaps, think about quitting the research and following music, in this case, as a career. I can't recommend that you quit, but only that you consider the options open to you. There is little that is worse than an unfulfilled life.
I suspect that things could get worse for you if you continue on as you are. It sounds like the research, and academia in general, is the distraction, not the other way 'round. Dropping music, however, seems like it would be extremely frustrating.
It is hard to be successful as an academic without passion for your subject and/or teaching. And hard to be successful in music without passion (and practice). Do what you love to the maximum extent you are able.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
